# Does laravel create connection with database every single time we run a query?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I wrote following code in my laravel application. This code is fetching data from four different tables and every table has totally different columns.

```
$response = [];
$response['test1'] = DB::table('test1')
->where('user_id','=',$user->id)
->whereNull('deleted_at')
->get();
$response['test2'] = DB::table('test2')
->where('user_id','=',$user->id)
->whereNull('deleted_at')
->get();
$response['test3'] = DB::table('test3')
->where('user_id','=',$user->id)
->whereNull('deleted_at')
->get();
return  ['success' => true,'data' => $response, 'errors'=> null];
```

Now just for curiosity, I want to know how this code will run.

1. How many connections will Laravel create while running the following
   queries?
2. If it creates a new connection for every single query then how it
   will affect my application if my DB server is on a different 
   continent?
3. And If it creates a single connection then for how much time the
   connection persists?

Comment: Technically you use the same connection, and multiple queries using that connection.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz technically correct is the best kind of correct

Comment: Answer no2: It depends in the type of queries you are running and your server capacities, also your client pc data transfer velocity and by that I mean, his internet speed.

Comment: Answer 3: The connection persist as long as is declared in your PDO settings in `connection_timeout`